# How can I call a batch file within another batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, cmd.exe, shell-script, sftp

trying to call a batch file within another batch file
the script completes the synchronization of the remote folders but then fails to call the other batch file.

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
/log="C:\Test\TestLog.log" /ini=nul ^
/command ^
"open sftp://test/ -hostkey=""ssh-dss 2048 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=""" ^
"synchronize remote \\Please\Send\Some\Help /Dir/Test" ^
"exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
echo Success
) else (
echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%

CALL movefile

pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move the [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command to be above the [exit](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) command or else it will exit before calling.

---

### What to Change

**This. . .**

```
exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
CALL movefile
pause
```

**Becomes this. . .**

```
CALL movefile
pause
exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

---

### Script

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
/log="C:\Test\TestLog.log" /ini=nul ^
/command ^
"open sftp://test/ -hostkey=""ssh-dss 2048 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=""" ^
"synchronize remote \\Please\Send\Some\Help /Dir/Test" ^
"exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
echo Success
) else (
echo Error
)

CALL movefile
pause
exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

> **Note:** *You will also want to ensure the batch script file being called actually exists so confirm that is the accurate location from
>   the executing batch script command that calls `movefile`.*